# Git uncommit message only

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm in this scenario pretty often and I don't know what to do.

1. I was changed something in a branch. Commited & pushed.
2. I was still working on same branch and somebody commited & pushed.
3. I was done changing and did **git commit -m "Blabla"** and pushed.
4. Git refused to push because repository is ahead and I may loose some changes

My idea is to:

- Go pre **git commit -m "blabla"** (<- this is where I'm stuck)
- stash changes
- Pull latest changes from repo
- Merge stash with working directory
- Commit once more
- Push

How do you resolve such "conflicts", or what is the best thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to drop/stash your commit. To resolve the conflict, use `git pull --rebase` and your commit from step 3 will be automatically rebased (stacked upon) the coworker's commits from step 2. After the rebase you will be able to push without the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948473/1507392) provides a better means of reaching your ultimate goal, but the answer for the question you asked is:

```
git reset HEAD~
```

That will rewind your current branch to point to the commit before the most recent one, but leave the index and working tree unchanged from their current states.